# How to retrieve certain entries only

Tags: filemaker

this is what I´m trying to achieve:

As per buttonclick I want to populate a textfield in table A with all records from table B that have a certain value.

Kind of:

```
"Catch all records in B where field XYZ is 99 and put them in this textfield."
```

Thanks for your help! I am using FM13!

Edit:
I have an "orders" table where the order-id is a serial number. I use it to write bills from the exact order to another table.
In certain cases an order is too less for one bill, so for them i create entries in another table called "smalljobs".

But: In the smalljobs table there is one field where i can enter a specific order-id - where i write the bill on, in my case say "5".
Let´s say orders "10, 12, and 13" are small-jobs. I have one big order where I can bill smalljobs onto - in my case maybe order "5".

All I want to do: add one script to populate a certain textfield with entries from "smalljobs" where my current order-id ("5") is identified as fitting, and get Title, Costs, etc.

Comment: Can you explain **why** would you want to do such thing? The basic idea in any relational database is to store data only once. Also please explain what (if any) is the relationship between the two tables and what do they represent in real life. Abstract names are not helpful in understanding the described situation.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation that well. It seems to me you want to have a **relationship** between the two tables based on matching OrderID, and show the related jobs in a **portal** placed on a layout of Orders. That way no copying is necessary and the display is updated automatically when you go to another order or when you add another related job.

Comment: Thanks, you mentioning "portal" made me find the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong from the beginning. I had to relate the "smalljobs" to a certain specific order-id, and get the informations I wanted via `GetNthRecord(fieldName;recordNumber)`.